# 2nd floor p trap for clawfoot tub

Tags: plumbing

I have a 1908 home with a clawfoot tub on the 2nd floor. It had some sort of lead box between the 1st floor rafters and under the permanent flooring that leaked. (A rat had chewed into it before I bought the home).  I want to replace it with a modern p trap but it is not accessable from down stairs, it would be enclosed below the flooring...can this be done OK?  There is no room between the bottom of the tub and top of the flooring, also cannot re-orient the tub so access can be made anywhere. I know it has to have been done in past...what is the answer?  thanxz, bob

Answer (score 2):

All too often these things are not installed with serviceability in mind - meaning you rip open the ceiling or floor when you do need to service them. Usually the ceiling is less trouble. Evidently that might be a once in a century operation, if this is the first time it's needed to be serviced...but it still makes me curse whoever entombed it and didn't provide an access panel.